# use dojo connect to fire a function other than particular event listener

Tags: dojo, event-listener

I have a function which rotates a slide show like startChangeImage(),My slideshow has to stop when there is a mouseover the slide show.

am tryin something like this

```
   dojo.connect(this.domNode,'onmouseover',this,this.stopChangeImage);
                    this.start = dojo.connect(this.domNode,'onmouseout',this,this.startChangeImage);

.....

stopChangeImage:function () {
            dojo.disconnect(this.start);

        }


........
```

the thing is it starts rotating only after mouse out I want it to work at all times except mouseover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are connecting the `onmouseout` event to `startChangeImage()`. If you want this slide show to start when the page loads, you could have an `init()` (or similar) function that gets called when the page loads to start the slide slow.

You also don't need the `this.` when using `dojo.connect()` with a context ([see here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/connect.html)). See the connect functions in the code sample below.

```
var pageClass = {

    stopChangeImage: function() { },

    startChangeImage: function() { },

    init: function() {

        this.startChangeImage();

        dojo.connect(this.domNode, 'onmouseover', this, 'stopChangeImage');
        this.start = dojo.connect(this.domNode, 'onmouseout', this, 'startChangeImage');
    }

};

dojo.addOnLoad(function() {

    pageClass.init();
});
```

The above code will start your slide slow when the page loads, but have it stop and start based on mouseover and mouseout.

Comment: You can remove the "this.start ="

Comment: I left it in since it was in the original example, and provides a link to the event to use with dojo.disconnect().